# Position an element from the end of the document at the top of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, xhtml

I have a `div` just before the `</body>` tag of the document (before the document ends).
And I want to display this div on the top of the page using CSS or JavaScript.

I know about `position:absolute;`. The problem is that if I use it, the div will show on top of other content that's located in the top, not before this content.

So is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @Alex:maybe i'm not fully understand, but why you don't put that div at the beginning?

Comment: because that div is for debug purposes, and it's content can change until the entire document finished displaying...

Comment: @Alex: You do realise that you can display any element anywhere on the page regardless of its flow position in the HTML source? And for such informational divs a `position:fixed;top:0;` seems perfect. And they don't really need to be put as first `body` child.

Comment: yes, but then it covers some big part of the page, especially where there's a lot of content... that div is there just to inform the webmaster of some stuff...

Comment: @Alex: do you append messages inside that div via JavaScript or does the content come preloaded via server side scripting?

Comment: no, it comes from server side, but it needs to be before `</body>` because messages can be added during page generation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **position:absolute** for the div element and then assign a **margin-top** to body element which equals the possible height of the div.

Comment: the div has variable height :(

Comment: I am not exactly sure if I understand your problem, but what you could do is to combine both "position:absolute" and "z-index:10" to set the level on which each div is located ( here you have to set probably more than one z-index i.e containing div to ensure x-browser )

Comment: @Alex: If you can use javascript to do this then on window load event set the document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.marginTop = <YOUR_DIV_REFERENCE>.clientHeight;

Comment: You may want to use `.offsetHeight` rather than `.clientHeight` to accommodate borders, and/or scrollbars... but a legit approach for sure!

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a way to drastically reposition an element, while keeping it within the inline flow. As you already mentioned, absolute positioning removes the element from inline flow--thus overlapping other content.

You could however use Jquery to clone the content, and append it somewhere near the top.  You could also query the height of the div, and use Jquery to set the body's top margin.

Both of these would allow it to respect the inline flow, but it's not using CSS as your question refers to; if you'd like, I can help with the Jquery.

**Edit:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {

        document.getElementById("content").style.marginTop = document.getElementById("errorDisplay").offsetHeight + "px";

        }
    </script>
```

I was playing with this in jsfiddle--It was actually acting weird... but it was definitely close to working. I was using a `wrapper` and `content` rather than manipulating the entire body (just a bit safer I think.) Make sure you add the `+ "px"` at the end of the command, otherwise it won't work.

Here's the fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/pVn2W/

As you can see, it's pushing the entire wrapper down rather than just the 'content'... using 'content' or 'wrapper' in the first argument doesn't change anything oddly enough.

Not exactly your model, but still an exercise in achieving the same goal--maybe this will get you a step closer :P

Comment: thanks, but I would need a pure javascript solution, as that div contains debug messages, and one of them could be "jquery failed to load" :)

Comment: @Alex you can see some javascript I was playing with... make sure you include the `+ "px"` at the end... Cybernate forgot to put it in :P

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to Cybernate's answer is to use **position:fixed** to do this.

This div will then however always be on top even when scrolling. It's great for a "notification" bar but irritating if you use it for the wrong kind of thing :)

Comment: This is correct positioning for such elements that are purely development informational. You always display them at the same position regardless of scroll or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

If using JavaScript is an option you can simply do this:

```
// For demonstration I am creating a <div id="mydiv">Hello World</div>
// Appending it to <body> means it goes to the very bottom of the body tag
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.id="mydiv";
div.innerHTML = "Hello World";
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(div);
// In your case I assume that the div is already present inside the HTML source
// just before </body>, So no need to do the above
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].insertBefore(
    document.getElementById("mydiv"),
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].firstChild
);
```

Copy paste the above code in the console for demonstration. If you're using jQuery, the above-mentioned code can be reduced to just one line.