# JavaScript - Move a element from the end of the document just after <body>

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Position an element from the end of the document at the top of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814007/position-an-element-from-the-end-of-the-document-at-the-top-of-the-page)

Hi

```
  <div id="debug">
   blabla
  </div>
</body>
```

How can I move the #debug div after at the beginning of the document, after `<body>`, using only javascript ?

Comment: Why post a duplicate? You can always edit your post(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814007/css-position-a-element-from-the-end-of-the-document-at-the-top-of-the-page/4814027#4814027) to provide more info?

Comment: I thought people would ignore it because it was marked as css initially :)

Comment: You can change the tags. In fact, I'll go do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('debug');
var body = document.body;
body.insertBefore(elem, body.firstChild);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/BuAau/

If you have jQuery available:

```
$('#debug').prependTo('body');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/BuAau/1/

Answer (score 1):

Javascript or jQuery?  In jQuery use:

```
$('body').append($('#debug'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var element = document.getElementById('debug');
document.body.insertBefore(element, document.body.firstChild);
```